# Accept Language list

Tags: content-negotiation, http-accept-language

I would like to react to the Accept_Language that a browser sends to a website.

Does anybody know where I can get a reliable list of all available Accept_Languages that the browser might send to a website?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'd look at the W3, http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-priorities.en.php and I'm sure the UN might have something to say about that. Or some of the market analysis firms that sniff data. I'd guess there's not the full 200+ you'd see in Brussels at a meeting of the convention of the conference of the panels.

Comment: The correct answer is that a browser *might* send anything, but that's probably not the answer you want to hear.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> [**IANA Language Subtag Registry page**](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry)
>
> This is the official location where you will find all subtags available for use in language tags.

W3 said it's the *authoritative list*. Plus, at the link below, there is a lot more information to be had, including descriptions and other ways of understanding the ways people label themselves.

[**http://www.w3.org/International/techniques/server-setup#multiviews**](http://www.w3.org/International/techniques/server-setup#multiviews)

Answer (score 5):

The IANA Language Subtag Registry page is surely the correct answer, but the list is a bit hard to parse.

I found this github repository that has a few scripts to parse it, and a set of ready-to-use JSON objects you can use in your projects:

https://github.com/mattcg/language-subtag-registry

It looks like the author is updating the repo every time the IANA list gets changed.