# Getting language/country name from accept-language in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n, http-accept-language

I'm attempting to gather some analytics based off of the user's `accept-language` header. It would be very helpful to turn `"en-US,en;q=0.8"` into `English (United States)`.

The only way I've really seen is using I18n and putting the name in the yaml file. This doesn't seem like a great solution because I would have to "translate" each possibility. It would make sense if I were using it for taking the user's preferred language and translating the page, but that's a different use case.

Is there any gem/gist I could use to find the language's display name?

Answer (score 1):

I would just copy the list of [language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) and [country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) codes from Wikipedia and transfer them into hashes:

```
LANGUAGE_CODES = {
  aa: 'Afar',
  ab: 'Abkhaz',
  # ...
  zu: 'Zulu'
}

COUNTRY_CODES = {
  AD: 'Andorra',
  AE: 'United Arab Emirates',
  # ...
  ZW: 'Zimbabwe'
}
```

with this hashes a simple method like the following should be able to extract the language and country information you are interested in:

```
def language_info(accepted_language)
  language, country = accepted_language.scan(/(\w{2})-(\w{2})/)

  if language && country
    "#{LANGUAGE_CODES[language]} (#{COUNTRY_CODES[country]})"
  end
end

# language_info(request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])
```

Comment: List can also be taken from IANA registry page - http://stackoverflow.com/a/13899628/794242